401 Unauthorized Error in React Project using Appwrite as Backend
I'm experiencing an issue with my React project that uses Appwrite as the backend. When I try to make a GET request, I receive a 401 Unauthorized error. The error message in the console is:
auth.js:50 GET https://cloud.appwrite.io/xyz/account 401 (Unauthorized) auth.js:55 User not authenticated. Returning null. 
I've checked my Appwrite configuration and ensured that I have the correct API key and project ID. However, I'm still getting this error. Has anyone else encountered this issue? How can I resolve it?
Project repo link: [GitHub repo] (https://github.com/codeitnav/React/tree/main/13megaBlog)
